# javascript & Form e-mail

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have following javascript for my form at the moment :

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('action') + $(this).serialize());
    alert("Thank You! \nTop Up for: <?php echo "$username" ?> Purchased Successfully");
    location.reload();
});
```

I basically now want to make it so that it sends an email everytime the form is submitted to an fixed email adress.
Basically everytime this script runs , it sshould send an email to stephan@test.com

Any ideas? I have no clue how to

Comment: You'll need to do that serverside, javascript does'nt send emails.

Comment: oh....can you explain how to...with php?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582950/mail-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mandrill and MailChimp (see [here](http://mandrill.com/)) if you don't have an SMTP server, these are useful in letting you create your own email templates. If you have an SMTP, then you should write a PHP functionality to support email sending. There is plenty of articles in the subject, just use a search engine.